# Openshift's rhc setup is waiting for a while

Tags: openshift

It's waiting for a while with doing nothing. Is it normal? When I go to the link on the last debug message with Chrome, a page is opened with login dialog. But my commandline is waiting without doing anything.

(I've installed with [this tutorial](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-debian-ubuntu.html#client-tools-dpkg))

**Here is the output:**

```
arjempagan@arjempagan-o-e-m:~$ rhc setup --debug
DEBUG: Using config file /home/arjempagan/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application
namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running server_stage

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit
enter to use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.


You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  919 ms
DEBUG: Server supports API versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG:    Using API version 1.7
DEBUG: Client API version 1.7 is not current. Refetching API
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  207 ms
DEBUG: Getting user info
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user
```

**An interesting output:**

```
$ rhc --version
rhc 0.0.0
```

Comment: is it hanging or waiting? - btw: the command line tool will probably add the needed authentication values into the header/parameters/cookies so it's not really the same as just browsing to the URL without giving those

Comment: The command is still running. You can see [here](https://vgy.me/rr2dFc.png) . I can cancel with ctrl + c. It didn't freeze.

Comment: interesting - maybe you have to update/redownload the `rhc`tools - or contact their support

Comment: OK. I've seen some reported bugs about it. I will reply my question now. Thank you too :)

Comment: btw: you usually can *abort* frozen/crashed apps with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: Oh, ok. I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found some reported bugs about it.

You can see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1291628) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhc/+bug/1531613):

**A quote for solution:**

> With Ubuntu 15.10 and rhc 1.35.4-3, rhc --version gives 0.0.0 and the setup hangs after GET (...) /broker/rest/user. Uninstalling the package (sudo apt-get remove rhc), installing the gem (sudo gem install rhc), and clearing bash's paths cache (hash -d rhc) did work.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). In other words: put a summary of the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04, and I couldn't make it work with the  @Interesting Knox's solution

Here are the steps taken, that worked for me and I hope will help to someone.

```
// removing debian package
sudo apt-get remove rhc

// installing rhc with gems
sudo gem install rhc

// version installed is rhc-1.38.4
// navigate to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4

cd /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4

// run setup
rhc setup
```